# fabric js image under overlay

Tags: canvas, overlay, fabricjs

I'm building a canvas with jquery and fabric.js library. I set overlay image using code:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('images/'+$_GET['id']+'.png', function(img) {
    img.set({
        left: (canvasW-img.width)/2,
        top: (canvasH-img.height)/2
    });                                     
    canvas2.setOverlayImage(img,canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2));
});
```

Add when load image using code:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, function(img) {
    img.set({
        left: (canvasW-w)/2,
        top: (canvasH-w*img.height/img.width)/2,
        scaleX: w/img.width,
        scaleY: w/img.width
    });                                     
    canvas2.add(img);
    canvas2.renderAll();
});
```

How can i made to change opacity of image to 0.5 when it is out of overlay image area?
Something like: http://postimg.org/image/weyf480ep/